# displaying RGB to a JLabel from a JSlider

Tags: java, swing, awt, listener, jslider

I'm trying to write a program that takes color values for red,green, and blue from a slider for each value and then displays it as an rgb value. I'm not exactly sure how to pull the rgb value from the three sliders but I think I am close. I can't figure out how to send the data to the JLabel or if I'm using the correct approach to get the rgb.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class MyColorChooser extends JFrame {

public final JSlider colorRed;
public static JSlider colorBlue;
public static JSlider colorGreen;
public static JLabel rgbValue;
public static JLabel green;
public static JLabel blue;
public int r;
public int g;
public int b;
Color c;

public Color getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(Color c) {
    this.c = new Color(r, g, b);
}

public MyColorChooser() {
    super("Slider Demo");

    JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel Panel3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel Panel4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    rgbValue = new JLabel("RGB Value");
    colorRed
            = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 0);
    colorBlue
            = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 0);
    colorGreen
            = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 0);
    colorRed.setMajorTickSpacing(5); // create tick every 10
    colorRed.setPaintTicks(true);
    colorRed.setPaintLabels(true);// paint ticks on slider
    colorBlue.setMajorTickSpacing(5); // create tick every 10
    colorBlue.setPaintTicks(true);
    colorBlue.setPaintLabels(true);//
    colorGreen.setMajorTickSpacing(5); // create tick every 10
    colorGreen.setPaintTicks(true);
    colorGreen.setPaintLabels(true);//

    colorRed.setLabelTable(colorRed.createStandardLabels(10));
    colorGreen.setLabelTable(colorGreen.createStandardLabels(10));
    colorBlue.setLabelTable(colorBlue.createStandardLabels(10));

    Panel1.add(colorRed);
    Panel2.add(colorGreen);
    Panel3.add(colorBlue);
    Panel4.add(rgbValue);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));
    add(Panel1);
    add(Panel2);
    add(Panel3);
    add(Panel4);

    colorGreen.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JSlider colorGreen = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            g = colorGreen.getValue();; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    });

    colorRed.addChangeListener(
            new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

            JSlider colorRed = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            r = colorRed.getValue();

        }
    });

    colorBlue.addChangeListener(
            new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JSlider colorBlue = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            b = colorBlue.getValue();//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

        }

    });

}

}
```

Comment: If you are using the standard JDK, you can see source files of examples under SwingSet2, JColorChooserDemo

Comment: I'd use an `Icon` specialised to show a `Color` in the `JLabel`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to send the data to the JLabel or if I'm using the correct approach to get the rgb

Well you need to invoke the `setText(....)` method on the label if you want the text to change.

So this means you will need to create a method like `updateLabel()` that you can invoke from each of the 3 listeners. In that method you will then get the values of your r, g, b, variables and format the string the way you want the text to appear in the label.

Comment: Oh sorry, I worded my question so that it was a little vague. I tried to use set text but I'm not sure how to convert the values I'm getting from the sliders into an rgb value.

Comment: @MichaelFogarty, What does "rgb value" mean to you? I don't understand your question?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want here... You want to take the value from 3 JSliders, probably from 0-255, and turn that into the background/foreground color on a JLabel? If so, then you will need to have the changeListener on each JSlider call `rgbValue.setForeground(new Color(r, g, b));`. If you want the JLabel to display a hexadecimal representation of your color, then it would be

`rgbValue.setText("RGB Value: #" + String.format("%02X", r) + String.format("%02X", g) + String.format("%02X", b));`